# Super quick CSS nested list won't hide

Tags: html, css, list, nested

I cannot figure out for the life of me why the nested lists aren't hiding. I copied a stylesheet I did at uni (that worked fine) nearly to the dot. But everything I try I can hide the second tier!

It's probably super simple, but I'm having that blank you get when you start for too long.

```css
/*Main Nav*/
#nav {
 height: 45px;
 width: 960px;
}
#nav li {
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color:white;
 width: 188px;
 height: 35px;
 padding-top: 10px;
}
#nav li:hover {
 background-color: white;
}
#nav ul {
 list-style: none;
}
#nav a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
 }
#nav a:hover {
 color: white; 
}
/*Sub Nav*/
#nav li ul {
 display: none;
}
#nav li:hover ul {
 display: block;
 position: aboslute;
}
#nav li li {
 display: block;
 background-color: gray;
}
#nav li li:hover {
 background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
 <ul>
     <li><a href="#1">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#1">Music</a></li>
         <ul>
             <li><a href="#2">Artists</a></li>
                <li><a href="#2">Free Tracks</a></li>
                <li><a href="#2">Labels</a></li>
                <li><a href="#2">Genres</a></li>
            </ul>
        <li><a href="#1">School</a></li>
            <ul>
             <li><a href="#2">Interviews</a></li>
                <li><a href="#2">Tips N Tricks</a></li>
                <li><a href="#2">Genre Class</a></li>
                <li><a href="#2">Promoters</a></li>
            </ul>
        <li><a href="#1">Events</a></li>
         <ul>
             <li><a href="#2">Coming Up</a></li>
                <li><a href="#2">Clubs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#2">Festivals</a></li>
            </ul>
        <li><a href="#2">About</a></li>
            <ul>
             <li><a href="#2">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#2">Upload Mix</a></li>
                <li><a href="#2">Shop</a></li>
            </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance, it's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

because you has wrong syntax in html, you didn't put sub ul into li, it's out of li.

correct:

```
<li><a href="#1">Music</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#2">Artists</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2">Free Tracks</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2">Labels</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2">Genres</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xsoLvv9u/

Answer (score 0):

There is no nested list (or at least not the way it should be). Look closely.

I think this is what you actually want.

```css
/*Main Nav*/
#nav {
 height: 45px;
 width: 960px;
}
#nav li {
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color:white;
 width: 188px;
 height: 35px;
 padding-top: 10px;
}
#nav li:hover {
 background-color: white;
}
#nav ul {
 list-style: none;
}
#nav a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
 }
#nav a:hover {
 color: white; 
}
/*Sub Nav*/
#nav li ul {
 display: none;
}
#nav li:hover ul {
 display: block;
 position: aboslute;
}
#nav li li {
 display: block;
 background-color: gray;
}
#nav li li:hover {
 background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
 <ul>
     <li><a href="#1">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#1">Music</a>
         <ul>
             <li><a href="#2">Artists</a></li>
                <li><a href="#2">Free Tracks</a></li>
                <li><a href="#2">Labels</a></li>
                <li><a href="#2">Genres</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>
        <li><a href="#1">School</a>
            <ul>
             <li><a href="#2">Interviews</a></li>
                <li><a href="#2">Tips N Tricks</a></li>
                <li><a href="#2">Genre Class</a></li>
                <li><a href="#2">Promoters</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>
        <li><a href="#1">Events</a>
         <ul>
             <li><a href="#2">Coming Up</a></li>
                <li><a href="#2">Clubs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#2">Festivals</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>
        <li><a href="#2">About</a>
            <ul>
             <li><a href="#2">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#2">Upload Mix</a></li>
                <li><a href="#2">Shop</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Omg I knew it was going to be something I've missed like that! Only learnt it the other day and tried for the first time here.
Thanks!

Comment: It's okay. We've all been there. The HTML syntax is not my favorite either.

Answer (score 0):

You have lot of issues. You should understand the level and sublevel concepts in html and css. I have fixed all your issues in the jsfiddle demo. Check it out.

**HTML**

```
  <div id="nav">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#1">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#1">Music</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#2">Artists</a></li>
            <li><a href="#2">Free Tracks</a></li>
            <li><a href="#2">Labels</a></li>
            <li><a href="#2">Genres</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#1">School</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#2">Interviews</a></li>
            <li><a href="#2">Tips N Tricks</a></li>
            <li><a href="#2">Genre Class</a></li>
            <li><a href="#2">Promoters</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#1">Events</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#2">Coming Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="#2">Clubs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#2">Festivals</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#2">About</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#2">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#2">Upload Mix</a></li>
            <li><a href="#2">Shop</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/xsoLvv9u/2/)